# How to solve this non-convex quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Consider the following quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x,y}{\text{minimize}} & a x^2 - b x y - c y\\ \text{subject to} & x \geq 1\\ & y \geq 5\end{array}$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given scalars. This problem arises as I was modelling a transistor's minimal dimensions $x$ and $y$ for it to operate in the saturation region and behave as an audio amplifier.

Unfortunately, I don't see this quadratic  objective as a convex. Therefore, I have no idea what might be a good approach for this problem. What I did essentially is assume $x = 1$ and compute $y$ directly.

Update: The goal of this question perhaps was to generalize the expression that I have ended up facing:

Let $x$ and $y$ be the length and width of the transistor accordingly, I seek to design a transistor that has a minimum length of $1$ $\mu\text{m}$ and minimum width of $5$ $\mu\text{m}$. The equations that govern the behavior of the transistor has landed me in the following equation :
$$
\theta(x,y)=1.5x^{2}-xy-0.05y
$$
The goal is to find optimal parameters $x$ and $y$ that minimizes $\theta$ while obeying these constraints. Graphically, and for other values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ there doesn't appear to be a convex form for the objective function.

Comment: maybe you should rephrase your objective function $\operatorname{minimize}_{x,y}\quad ax^{2}-bxy-cx=0$ seems incorrect

Comment: I managed to graph it but the resulting graph and taking the constraints into considerations appears to show solutions lying mostly on flat regions

Comment: @Steph I apologize for this minor mistake, I have fixed it accordingly

Comment: Correction to my comment on graphical simulation: I took $a=2, b=1,$ and $c=0.5$

Comment: @SPARSE: can you write the exact expression of the problem (with the values of $a, b, c$ and all the constraints)?

Comment: considering $x^2 > x$ for $x>1$, I think minimum would be along the line $x=1$

Comment: @cvanaret I have updated my question

Comment: Since no one has answered yet, there is no need to append `Update` sections. Merely refine the whole question. Do not worry if some comments become obsolete.

Comment: What do you know about $a,b,c$? Do you know their signs, at least?

Comment: Why don't you split the problem into several parts? Since the function is nice and smooth, you can find the points where the derivatives are zero. You can also solve the problem for $x=1$, and you can solve the problem for the case $y=5$. Then the minimum is either one of the points where all derivatives are zero, one of the points where $x=1$ and the derivative with respect to $y$ is zero, one of the points where $y=5$ and the derivative with respect to $x$ is $0$, or the point $(x=1,y=5)$.

Comment: @SPARSE Thanks. I don't understand "the equation that governs the transistor": it's an expression, not an equation (it's not $\theta(x, y) = 0$, for example). Are you sure it's the objective and not a constraint?

Comment: Your problem does not assume minimum. You can take $x=1$ and $y$ going to infinity and your objective function will be shown unbounded below.